# Sonar Plugin - View Source Code

Tags: plugins, abap, sonarqube

I'm writing a small Sonar Plugin for Abap Code. I alread have presented metrics in Sonar, and also have the source Code of some Abap Files in the Sonar Database (i checked it with a sql client). But now I really have no clue how could I present this source code with sonar. I already looked through the sonar source code and some sonar plugins (like the CXXPlugin https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-cxx which also have the Function to output the source Code), but I didn't get smarter. Is there an easy way how to present source code with the sonar api? Is there any kind of SourceViewer part of the Sonar Core (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar).

---

EDIT: I'm now one step closer but I have a problem with the drilldown-view. My erb-file has the following code snippet:

```
 %= format_measure(loc_measure, :suffix => '', :url => url_for_drilldown(loc_measure)) -%>
```

But my drilldown view do not list the sources which I have in my folder which was analysed by sonar:
[image]

In my Database I looked at the table 'projects':
[image]

Afterwards I tried to directly link in the drilldown view to a source file (in that case with the id 122) and it worked:
[image]

So my question is, why are the subfolder and source files not listed like classes and package in a normal Java project?

Comment: Sorry I can'T help you with your Sonar issue - but I'm curious: What is it you're trying to accomplish at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at some of our open-source language plugins that we develop for Sonar. For instance, you can go and see the [Javascript plugin](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-javascript) - which is probably a better option that the CXX plugin that is not developed by us and there that may not fully comply with our conventions and coding best-practices & guidelines.

To sum up:

- Create a source importer like the [JavascriptSourceImporter](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-javascript/blob/master/sonar-javascript-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/javascript/core/JavaScriptSourceImporter.java)
- Create a colorizer like what you can find in the "[org.sonar.plugins.javascript.colorizer](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-javascript/tree/master/sonar-javascript-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/javascript/colorizer)" package
- And obviously do not forget to declare those extensions in your plugin class

Comment: thanks a lot, this propably will help me a lot. the sourceimporter is already part of my plugin but I will take a closer look to the colorizer plugin now.

Comment: I edited my question, after I ran into another problem related to the source code view in sonar. Maybe you can help me again with my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156710/sonar-plugin-view-source-code